# Load all related tables in struct or json with seaOrm in rust

Tags: json, rust, struct, sea-orm

I'm trying to load a table with all related tables joined in rust with seaOrm. After trying for a while I managed to write a select statement which seem to load all the tables as requested. However I can't get them in a struct or json format as desired. When using `into_json()` all data is displayed but for every change a new row is generated (like in SQL).

```rust
  let data =  Sale::find_by_id(1)
    .join(JoinType::InnerJoin, sale::Relation::Product.def())
    .columns(product::Column::iter())

    .join(JoinType::InnerJoin, product::Relation::ProductPart.def())
    .columns(product_part::Column::iter())

    .join(JoinType::InnerJoin, sale::Relation::Seller.def())
    .columns(seller::Column::iter())

    .into_json()

    .all(&db)
    .await?;
```

- Each sale has multiple `Product`
- Each product has multiple `ProductParts`
- Each sale has one `Seller`

If I just join `Sale` and `Seller` I get 1 line of result. As soon as I join `Product` I get a few multiple lines which are again multiplied if joined with `ProductPart` for each `ProductPart`.

Another problem here seems to be that when the same column name in different tables exist this is overwritten. I've name both in `Sale` and `Product` and the name key in the json gets the value of the `Product` name field.

How can I get this is in some kind of stuct or json format like this:

```rust
#[derive(FromQueryResult, Debug)]
struct SaveStruct {
  sale_uid: Uuid,
  name: Option<String>,
  products: Vec<Product>,
  seller: Seller,
}

struct Product{
  uid: Uuid,
  name: Option<String>,
  parts: Vec<ProductPart>,
}

struct Seller{
  name: Option<String>,
}
```

Or even better in json like this:

```rust
{
  "sale_uid": 1,
  "name": "sale_name",
  "products": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Product 1",
      "parts": [
        {
          "type": "type",
          "id": 0
        },
        {
          "type": "type",
          "id": 1
        },
      ]
    }
  ],
  "seller": {
    "name": "name",
  }
}
```